# How to choose data by headers descriptively in R .CSV data?

Tags: r, csv

I want to choose data descriptively by headers. 
Here, an example to choose IDs of males in .CSV data. 
You can do `data[3] == "males"` with the following data but I would like to do `data[Gender] == "males"` to avoid any mistakes. 
File data.csv

```
ID,Age,Gender
100,69,male
101,75,female
102,84,female
103,,male
104,66,female
```

Code where lastline pseudocode

```
data = read.csv("/home/masi/data.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ",")
str(data)

# PSseudocode
#data.Gender == "male"
#data[Gender] == "male"
```

### Eli

Now, we have a list of males, and we want to return the IDs corresponding to those males

```
eliData <- data$Gender == "male"
# to return IDs corresponding to males
# Pseudocode
data$ID == eliData
```

Pseudocode returns false for all.

Motivation: to make characteristic correlation [matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329062/54964) for different epidemiological groups where each data point has many own characteristics.

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$` notation in R for this. `data$Gender == "male"` is what you want.
To get the `id`s from the rows where `"male"` is the gender you can do this

```
males <- data$Gender == "male"
maleIDs <- data[which(males), ]$ID
```

Here Eli's great function for the general task

```
getIDs <- function(age, gender) {
        data <- read.csv("/home/masi/data.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ",")

        gender <- data$Gender == gender
        if (length(age) == 1) {
                ages <- data$Age == age
        } else {
                ages <- (data$Age >= age[1] & data$Age <= age[2])
        }
        genderIDs <- data[which(gender), ]$ID
        ageIDs <- data[which(ages), ]$ID
        intersect(ageIDs, genderIDs)
}
# So if you called this as getIDs(c(20, 30), "male")
# You'd get the ids of all males with age >= 20 and <= 30
```

Comment: @Masi Can you give an example of what you want as a result? I'm not fully understanding what you're asking here.

Comment: @Masi Changed my code to give you more what you want

Comment: @Masi Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127003/discussion-between-eli-sadoff-and-masi).

Comment: @Masi `R` has an implicit return. I'm not exactly sure why `return` doesn't work though.

Comment: Pretty much. [Here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) is an explanation.