# How to overload function parameters in R?

Tags: r

Simplified code where two parameter `age` and `gender`; however, I would like to pick cases only by `gender` or `age`; I am thinking how you can overload to `getIDs(age)` and `getIDs(gender)` without multiplicating same code again and again; assume you have 50 parameters etc; I tried `getIDs(age, "")` but I it is not a good idea

```
getIDs <- function(age, gender) {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330110/54964

    ageIDs <- c(1,2,3)
    genderIDs # dummy code here to indicate that do not use genderIDs if gender ""

    intersect(ageIDs, genderIDs)
}
```

Main data

```
ID,Age,Gender
100,69,male
101,75,female
102,84,female
103,,male
104,66,female
```

Data 2

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = 100:104, Age = c(69L, 75L, 84L, NA, 66L), Gender = 
c("male", "female", "female", "male", "female")), .Names = c("ID", "Age", 
"Gender"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Similarly for age: if `age==""`, do not include `subset`ageIDs` in.

Some parameter for all male would be great such that you do not need to do explicitly `"male", "male", ...`.

### Algorithm based on Roman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348529/54964)

I think this strategy is very challenging with 50 parameters so better way is still needed

```
getIDs <- function(age, gender) {
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330110/54964
# So if you called this as getIDs(c(20, 30), "male")
# You'd get the ids of all males with age >= 20 and <= 30
# 
# NULL = ALL
# getIDs(age = c(1,2), gender = NULL)
# getIDs(age = NULL, gender = "male")
        data <- read.csv("/home/masi/data.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ",")

        if (is.null(gender)) {
                genderIDs <- data$ID
        } else {
                gender <- data$Gender == gender
                genderIDs <- data[which(gender), ]$ID
        }

        if (is.null(age)) {
                age <- c(0,130)
        }
        if (length(age) == 1) {
                ages <- data$Age == age
        } else {
                ages <- (data$Age >= age[1] & data$Age <= age[2])
        }
        ageIDs <- data[which(ages), ]$ID

        intersect(ageIDs, genderIDs)
}
```

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.1.1

Comment: "getIDs(age) and getIDs(gender)" can *maybe* be distinguished if age is a number and gender is a string. There are only so many data types in R, though, and if you have 50 of them that you want the function to match without passing the arg name, there'll be trouble.

Comment: I read you as asking that getIDs(45) and getIDs("male") should work... right?

Comment: For 50 parameters, a named vector may be a better solution.

Comment: See edit of my question if you find any potential solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can write a general function where you can pass whatever condition you like to the function as a string, and it'll return the values. This scales easily to multiple parameters, as long as your condition string can be evaluated by dplyr (the outputs were generated using the dataframe you provided [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330096/how-to-choose-data-by-headers-descriptively-in-r-csv-data/40330110#40330110):

```
library(dplyr)
getIDs <- function(conditon)
{
  data <- read.csv("/home/masi/data.csv", header = T)
  df <- data %>% filter_(conditon) %>% .$ID
}

getIDs("Gender == 'male'")
# [1] 100 103

getIDs("Age > 30")
# [1] 100 101 102 104

getIDs("Gender == 'male' & Age > 30")
# [1] 100
```

---

If you don't need to read in `data` within the function, the function can be written like

```
getIDs <- . %>% filter_(DF, .) %>% .$ID
```

Defining functions this way is a feature of magrittr chains.

---

If you want to pass a sequence of queries as arguments:

```
getIDs <- function(...){
    DF %>% filter_(...) %>% .$ID
} 

getIDs("Gender == 'male'", "Age > 30")
# [1] 100
```

---

If you want to get the result sorted by one of the parameters, add an `arrange` to the dplyr pipline:

```
getIDs <- function(..., by = NULL){
    DF %>% filter_(...) %>% { if (!is.null(by))  arrange_(., by) else . } %>% .$ID
} 

getIDs("Gender == 'female'", "Age > 10", by = "Age")
# [1] 104 101 102

# descending order:
getIDs("Gender == 'female'", "Age > 10", by = "desc(Age)")
# [1] 102 101 104
```

Comment: It uses a completely different paradigm. At the end of the day, with fifty parameters, you'll have to do a lot of manual enumeration of the conditions. I find it easier to work with explicit conditions, and a clear chain of the steps of transformations I make. Others like the conciseness of base R.

Comment: Instead of reading in data each time the function is called, probably better to assign it to the environment. Also in that case you can write the whole function using a chain: `getIDs <- . %>% filter_(DF, .) %>% .$ID;
environment(getIDs)$DF <- 
    structure(list(ID = 100:104, Age = c(69L, 75L, 84L, NA, 66L), 
    Gender = c("male", "female", "female", "male", "female")), .Names = c("ID", 
    "Age", "Gender"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

; getIDs("Gender == 'male'")`

Comment: That is correct @Frank. I was only following Masi's example in the OP. Obviously, reading it in every time is inefficient.

Comment: **Can you return IDs in Age descending or ascending order by this method?** Etc pseudocode  `getIDs("Gender == 'male'", "Age > 30", "Age.ascednig")`.

Comment: absolutely: `getIDs <- function(..., by = "Age"){ DF %>% filter_(...) %>% arrange_(by) %>% .$ID }`.
I added it to my answer

Comment: See my answer. If you ignore the `by` argument, the output wont be sorted by any order. If you specify it, it'll be sorted by ascending order. If you want descending order, you can specify `"getIDs("Gender == 'male', by="desc(Age)")"`

Answer (score 5):

You can specify default values to your parameters and catch them downstream.

For example, if you make `age = NULL`, you can catch it using

```
if (is.null(age)) {
    # do something
}
```

The same holds true for other parameters. Another fine option is to use `NA`, caught by `is.na` function.

#### edit

Following the discussion, fifty parameters is a hand full to handle in any case. You have several options, depending on your needs.

If all arguments are of the same data type, you can use a named vector, e.g.

```
x <- c(arg1 = "1", arg2 = "this")
```

If you have different data types and you do not want them to be coerced to one type (numeric will be coerced to character, if one parameter is character, try `c(1, "2")`), you can use a list.

```
x <- list(par1 = 1,
          par2 = "2",
          par3 = factor(3),
          par4 = TRUE)
```

Working with lists is very natural in R, you can manipulate it using e.g. `sapply` or `lapply`. You could find all numeric values

```
> x[sapply(x, is.numeric)]
$par1
[1] 1
```

Or just based on name alone

```
> x[grepl(paste("par", 1:2, sep = "", collapse = "|"), names(x))]
$par1
[1] 1

$par2
[1] "2"
```

Comment: I never use it, but `missing` also seems to sort of do it, like `f = function(a, b) if (missing(b)) a else b; f(1,2); f(1)`..? Oh never mind, reread the OP's question and am now thoroughly confused.

Comment: @Frank Can you please extend your comment into an answer so I can understand it better? I made an implication of Roman's answer into the body and it has serious limitations with 50 parameters. Very difficult to maintain it.

Comment: @Roman Can you please compare your proposals to yeedle's proposal which I like a lot because of its flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

Following Roman's idea, I'd maybe use a list:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

getIDs <- function(L) DF[L, on=names(L), ID]
```

Usage:

```
> getIDs(list(Gender = "male"))
[1] 100 103
> getIDs(list(Gender = "male", Age = NA))
[1] 103
```

Data

```
DF = structure(list(ID = 100:104, Age = c(69L, 75L, 84L, NA, 66L), 
Gender = c("male", "female", "female", "male", "female")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Age", "Gender"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Masi I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Masi Sorry, I still don't follow.

Comment: @Masi Ok. Yeah, that makes sense. The approach in this answer only works for equality testing. If you want a sequence of queries, then yeedle's is the best fit. I've edited it to demonstrate.