# How to avoid showing headers in STOUT of R data.table?

Tags: r

I am trying to avoid showing headers in R's STOUT of `data.table` output. Akrun says in the related thread the the null route may be possible with `print`.

> If you are not okay with the NULL route, then you may have to create a custom function for print by modifying the existing print

Code

```
library(data.table)

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/43706344/54964

DF[time < 8]
```

Output where I want to avoid the first header line in STOUT

```
#    Field time  T Experiment time_expected    timeN
# 1: Acute  0.0  0          A             6 0.000000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the `unname`

```
unname(DF[time <8])[]

# 1: Acute 0.0  0 A 6 0.000000
# 2:    An 7.7 26 B 6 1.283333
# 3:    Fo 0.0  0 B 5 0.000000
# 4: Acute 7.5  1 C 6 1.250000
# 5:    An 7.9 43 C 6 1.316667
# 6:    En 0.0  0 C 6 0.000000
# 7:    Fo 5.4  1 C 5 1.080000
# 8:    An 7.8 77 D 6 1.300000
# 9:    En 0.0  0 D 6 0.000000
#10:    Fo 0.0  0 D 5 0.000000
#11: Acute 0.0  0 E 6 0.000000
#12:    An 7.9 60 E 6 1.316667
#13:    Fo 0.0  0 E 5 0.000000
#14:    Fo 7.9  3 F 5 1.580000
```

---

One option to avoid the empty line would be

```
cat(trimws(capture.output(unname(DF[time <8]))[-1]) , sep="\n")
#1: Acute 0.0  0 A 6 0.000000
#2:    An 7.7 26 B 6 1.283333
#3:    Fo 0.0  0 B 5 0.000000
#4: Acute 7.5  1 C 6 1.250000
#5:    An 7.9 43 C 6 1.316667
#6:    En 0.0  0 C 6 0.000000
#7:    Fo 5.4  1 C 5 1.080000
#8:    An 7.8 77 D 6 1.300000
#9:    En 0.0  0 D 6 0.000000
#10:    Fo 0.0  0 D 5 0.000000
#11: Acute 0.0  0 E 6 0.000000
#12:    An 7.9 60 E 6 1.316667
#13:    Fo 0.0  0 E 5 0.000000
#14:    Fo 7.9  3 F 5 1.580000
```

For better formatting, the `trimws` could be avoided

```
cat(capture.output(unname(DF[time <8]))[-1] , sep="\n")
# 1: Acute 0.0  0 A 6 0.000000
# 2:    An 7.7 26 B 6 1.283333
# 3:    Fo 0.0  0 B 5 0.000000
# 4: Acute 7.5  1 C 6 1.250000
# 5:    An 7.9 43 C 6 1.316667
# 6:    En 0.0  0 C 6 0.000000
# 7:    Fo 5.4  1 C 5 1.080000
# 8:    An 7.8 77 D 6 1.300000
# 9:    En 0.0  0 D 6 0.000000
#10:    Fo 0.0  0 D 5 0.000000
#11: Acute 0.0  0 E 6 0.000000
#12:    An 7.9 60 E 6 1.316667
#13:    Fo 0.0  0 E 5 0.000000
#14:    Fo 7.9  3 F 5 1.580000
```

Comment: How can you avoid the newline there? Assume you print one line before the data that you would like to be together with the data. Etc `field <- "Orto"; sprintf("%s ", field);`.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  Did you meant to have `trimws(capture.output(unname(DF[time <8]))[-1])`

Comment: Yes, I do. perfect!

Comment: I expanded another similar case here about the presentation of like Vim's `tabstop` http://stackoverflow.com/q/43715031/54964