# How to have a tabstop length in STOUT of R data.table column?

Tags: r

I would like to show subsequent prints of the data more consistently in R `data.table`. 
In Vim, you can do it with `tapstop` and `csv.vim`, for instance. 
Code

```
library(data.table)

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/43706344/54964

DF[time < 8]

# print other data
DF[time < 10]
```

Output where the location of the second column varies because of varying length of items in the second column from (7.7 to 10.8)

```
                      Z A_t AtPE
1:                    A 7.7 1.28
2:                    B 9.6 1.60
[1] other data
1:                    C  9.0 1.50
2:                    A 10.8 1.80
```

Expected output

```
                      Z  A_t AtPE
1:                    A  7.7 1.28
2:                    B  9.6 1.60
[1] other data
1:                    C  9.0 1.50
2:                    A 10.8 1.80
```

### Example of my commands

```
field <- "Acute"
sprintf("%s ", field)
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/43714690/54964
cat(capture.output(unname(DF[order(time)][time < 15 & Field == field, .(Field)])[])[-1], sep="\n")

field <- "An"
sprintf("%s ", field)
cat(capture.output(unname(DF[order(time)][time < 15 & Field == field, .(Field)])[])[-1], sep="\n")

field <- "En"
sprintf("%s ", field)
cat(capture.output(unname(DF[order(time)][time < 15 & Field == field, .(Field)])[])[-1], sep="\n")
```

Comment: You meant to use the variable defined inside the `data.table`, instead of the `cat`?

Comment: The value's you mentione are not i nyour example.  If i use `field <- "Acute";
 DF[order(time)][time < 15 & Field == field, .(Field)]#
   Field
1: Acute
2: Acute
3: Acute
4: Acute
5: Acute
6: Acute`

Comment: I guess I understand what you meant.  Instead of subsetting each separately, why not put it in a loop and do it i.e. `lapply(c("Acute", "An", "En"), function(x) DF[order(time)[time < 15 & Field == x, .(Field)])` the other parts would be the same as my update

Comment: Could you please check my update.  The first name is a bit long, so the format width needs to be adjusted for it

Comment: Also, I guess `v1 <- format(trimws(v1), width = max(nchar(v1)+max(nchar(nm1))), justify = "left")` the justify = left seems to be better here

Comment: @akrun Even better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this by placing it in a `list` and then do the `capture.output` with some tweaking

```
v1 <- capture.output(lapply(list(DF[time < 8], DF[time < 10]), unname))
v2 <- v1[!grepl("\\[", v1)]
i1 <- v2=="" &  seq_along(v2) != length(v2)
v2[i1] <- sprintf("[%d] other data", seq_along(i1[i1]))
```

and now we print it

```
cat(v2[trimws(v2)!=""], sep="\n")
# 1: Acute 0.0  0 A 6 0.000000
# 2:    An 7.7 26 B 6 1.283333
# 3:    Fo 0.0  0 B 5 0.000000
# 4: Acute 7.5  1 C 6 1.250000
# 5:    An 7.9 43 C 6 1.316667
# 6:    En 0.0  0 C 6 0.000000
# 7:    Fo 5.4  1 C 5 1.080000
# 8:    An 7.8 77 D 6 1.300000
# 9:    En 0.0  0 D 6 0.000000
#10:    Fo 0.0  0 D 5 0.000000
#11: Acute 0.0  0 E 6 0.000000
#12:    An 7.9 60 E 6 1.316667
#13:    Fo 0.0  0 E 5 0.000000
#14:    Fo 7.9  3 F 5 1.580000
#[1] other data
# 1: Acute 0.0   0 A 6 0.000000
# 2:    An 9.0 120 A 6 1.500000
# 3:    Fo 9.2   2 A 5 1.840000
# 4: Acute 8.3   1 B 6 1.383333
# 5:    An 7.7  26 B 6 1.283333
# 6:    Fo 0.0   0 B 5 0.000000
# 7: Acute 7.5   1 C 6 1.250000
# 8:    An 7.9  43 C 6 1.316667
# 9:    En 0.0   0 C 6 0.000000
#10:    Fo 5.4   1 C 5 1.080000
#11: Acute 8.6   2 D 6 1.433333
#12:    An 7.8  77 D 6 1.300000
#13:    En 0.0   0 D 6 0.000000
#14:    Fo 0.0   0 D 5 0.000000
#15: Acute 0.0   0 E 6 0.000000
#16:    An 7.9  60 E 6 1.316667
#17:    Fo 0.0   0 E 5 0.000000
#18: Acute 8.3   4 F 6 1.383333
#19:    An 8.2 326 F 6 1.366667
#20:    Fo 7.9   3 F 5 1.580000
```

#### Update

We need to explicitly call the `justify` in `format` to align it

```
v1 <- do.call(c, lapply(list(DF[time < 8], DF[time < 10]),
     function(x) capture.output(unname(x))))
v1 <- format(trimws(v1), width = max(nchar(v1)), justify = "right")
i1 <- trimws(v1)=="" & seq_along(v1) != 1
v1[i1] <- format(sprintf("[%d] other data", seq_along(i1[i1])),
           width = max(nchar(v1)), justify = "left")
```

Now, we call the `cat`

```
cat(v1[-1], sep="\n")
#  1: Acute 0.0  0 A 6 0.000000
#  2:    An 7.7 26 B 6 1.283333
#  3:    Fo 0.0  0 B 5 0.000000
#  4: Acute 7.5  1 C 6 1.250000
#  5:    An 7.9 43 C 6 1.316667
#  6:    En 0.0  0 C 6 0.000000
#  7:    Fo 5.4  1 C 5 1.080000
#  8:    An 7.8 77 D 6 1.300000
#  9:    En 0.0  0 D 6 0.000000
# 10:    Fo 0.0  0 D 5 0.000000
# 11: Acute 0.0  0 E 6 0.000000
# 12:    An 7.9 60 E 6 1.316667
# 13:    Fo 0.0  0 E 5 0.000000
# 14:    Fo 7.9  3 F 5 1.580000
#[1] other data                
# 1: Acute 0.0   0 A 6 0.000000
# 2:    An 9.0 120 A 6 1.500000
# 3:    Fo 9.2   2 A 5 1.840000
# 4: Acute 8.3   1 B 6 1.383333
# 5:    An 7.7  26 B 6 1.283333
# 6:    Fo 0.0   0 B 5 0.000000
# 7: Acute 7.5   1 C 6 1.250000
# 8:    An 7.9  43 C 6 1.316667
# 9:    En 0.0   0 C 6 0.000000
#10:    Fo 5.4   1 C 5 1.080000
#11: Acute 8.6   2 D 6 1.433333
#12:    An 7.8  77 D 6 1.300000
#13:    En 0.0   0 D 6 0.000000
#14:    Fo 0.0   0 D 5 0.000000
#15: Acute 0.0   0 E 6 0.000000
#16:    An 7.9  60 E 6 1.316667
#17:    Fo 0.0   0 E 5 0.000000
#18: Acute 8.3   4 F 6 1.383333
#19:    An 8.2 326 F 6 1.366667
#20:    Fo 7.9   3 F 5 1.580000
```

#### Update2

Based on the OP's comments

```
nm1 <- c("Acute", "An", "En")
v1 <- do.call(c, lapply(nm1, function(x) 
    capture.output(unname(DF[order(time)][time < 15 & Field == x, .(Field)]))))
v1 <- format(trimws(v1), width = max(nchar(v1)+max(nchar(nm1))), justify = "right")
i1 <- trimws(v1)=="" 
v1[i1] <- format(sprintf("[%d] %s", seq_along(i1[i1]), nm1),
          width = max(nchar(v1)), justify = "left")
cat(v1, sep="\n")
```

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  I think it has to do the insertion of 'other data' there.  I tried `v1 <- do.call(c, lapply(list(DF[time < 8], DF[time < 10]), function(x) capture.output(unname(x))));i1 <- trimws(v1)=="" & seq_along(v1) != 1;v1[i1] <- sprintf("[%d] other data", seq_along(i1[i1])); cat(v1, sep="\n")`

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  I did some more manipulation to keep the same character length., but something with `cat` is still making it pushed `v1 <- do.call(c, lapply(list(DF[time < 8], DF[time < 10]), function(x) capture.output(unname(x))));
v1 <- format(v1, width = max(nchar(v1)));
i1 <- trimws(v1)=="" & seq_along(v1) != 1;
 v1[i1] <- format(sprintf("[%d] other data", seq_along(i1[i1])), width = max(nchar(v1)));cat(v1, sep="\n")`  have to look into the `cat` function

Comment: Now the nchar is same `nchar(v1)#
 [1] 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30`  I have to go now.  Will check later

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  Please check the updated post.  I think it is the `justify` that created the trouble

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  I am not sure I understand your query

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Okay, I thought your values will be `Other1`, `Other2` etc.  In that case, keep it as a vector and paste i.e. `v2 <- c("A", "B"); format(sprintf("[%d] %s", seq_along(i1[i1]), v2), ...`

Comment: Beautiful output! I confirm that Update 2 works and gives aesthetically satisfying output.