# How to have R columns as one big column?

Tags: r

Column one  (`x[, 1]`) has the original signal. 
Column 2 (`x[, 2]`) has the improved signal. 
I want to have them now as a single column for the following line. 
Code for single column reference in `x[, 1]`

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/40329062/54964
M <- cor(sapply(files, function(x) x[, 1]))
```

Pseudocode `x[, 1:2]` for taking both columns in a long column - second column after the first one

```
M_both <- cor(sapply(files, function(x) x[, 1:2]))
```

I think this can be done by many measures, maybe concatenating also in R. 
I have about 100x2 cases so the matrix sizes are 100x100 x2.

`c(x[,1],x[,2])` is not making a big column.

Structure of `files` by `str(files)`

```
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   541650 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ V1: num [1:541650] -0.13 -0.165 -0.17 -0.135 -0.12 -0.11 -0.12 -0.135 -0.155 -0.145 ...
  ..$ V2: num [1:541650] -0.535 -0.515 -0.505 -0.505 -0.505 -0.5 -0.495 -0.49 -0.48 -0.48 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   541650 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ V1: num [1:541650] -0.2 -0.195 -0.185 -0.18 -0.17 -0.16 -0.16 -0.16 -0.155 -0.145 ...
  ..$ V2: num [1:541650] -0.43 -0.38 -0.375 -0.515 -0.605 -0.575 -0.525 -0.505 -0.495 -0.49 ...
```

### Output of Luke1018's answer

I do

```
M_both <- cor(sapply(files, function(x) c(x[, 1],x[, 2]) ))
makeMatrixPlot(M_both, ids)
```

Fig. 1 Initial output on left with single columns, while output of two columns at the right-hand side

[image]

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.1.1

Comment: I dont really understand what you're asking. If you want to put two columns together, you can just do `c(x[,1],x[,2])` or `rbind` or `reshape2::melt` if it helps...

Comment: Can you provide the structure of "files"? Is it a list of two matrices? So for the first line, are you trying to find the correlation between the first column of file1 and the first column of file2? I don't understand what you meant by "taking both columns in a long column" either. Please clarify.

Comment: @JanSila Please, see the body.

Comment: you got a list of two data frames. do you want to put V1,V2 and V1,V2 after each other?

Comment: You want all the data frames to become a single column or a each one of them to become a single column and keep the list structure? I guess you could just do `unlist(files)` or `lapply(files, unlist)` - depending on your desired output. You can also specify `, use.names = FALSE` within `unlist` if you don't want a named vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.frame(c(x[, 1], x[, 2]))` will create your "one big column". However, your function is not reassigning any new value to `files` - so naturally the structure will not have changed.